# Automatically group member functions based on constness

Tags: c++, doxygen

Can `doxygen` automatically create groups like "Accessors" and "Modifiers", i.e. group member functions based on `const`-ness? If not, are these groups common enough that one should consider spending the effort to create them manually?

Comment: Many classes have const and non-const versions of the same methods.  I personally would not expect or prefer to see those split into different parts of the documentation.  So doing it purely by declared `const`ness might be less than ideal.  Consider also the case where an otherwise-const method is not marked const for some implementation reason like caching.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Regarding your last sentence: No, that's what `mutable` member variables are for.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: `mutable` is one way to solve it, but not the only way used in practice.  If you want to require programs to be rewritten to accommodate Doxygen, well, good luck!

Comment: @JohnZwinck: `mutable` is the only good way to solve it. That does not mean there is a lot of (legacy) code which does it wrong, of course. If you document legacy (or otherwise incorrect) code with missing `const` specifiers, then you should explain that fact in the documentation so that clients are aware that `const_cast` is safe to use.